# Sendgrid: render an ejs template and then send as an email.

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, sendgrid

So I have index.ejs which renders perfectly when I start my nodejs server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title<%= title %></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><%= title %></h1>
        <h3><%= yesterday %></h3>
        <h1> Number of Spins: <%= count %></h1>
        <h1> Active User Count: <%= userCount %></h1>
        <h1> Users that did not validate: </h1>
        <ul>

            <% for(var i=0; i<unvalid.length; i++) {%>

                <li><%= unvalid[i] %></li>
            <% } %>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

The thing is, I would like to send this on an email using Sendgrid. So far what i've been doing is using the .setHTML method to sort of "brute-force" it:

```
email.setHtml('<h1> Spotluck Daily Report </h1><h3>'+ yesterday + '</h3><h1> Number of Spins: '+cuenta+'</h1><h1> Active User Count: '+userCount+'</h1>' +'<h1> Users that did not validate: </h1>');
```

But this would never work because it would be unable to render the ejs for loop. So my question is: How do I tell the Sendgrid email to render my ejs and send it as an email without having to resort to .setHTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `ejs.render(str, subs)` [function](https://github.com/tj/ejs#usage) inside of `setHtml`.

```
email.setHtml(ejs.render(yourTemplate, {foo: 'bar'}));
```

But I'd recommend using SendGrid's [Template Engine](https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Templates/index.html) since our node library [supports it](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs#templates).

Comment: So i'm trying to do email.setHtml(ejs.render('../path/to/index.ejs', { //set the template vars here })), but when I send the email it just prints out the '../path/to/index.ejs' on the email. Suggestions?

Comment: You'd need to use something like [readFileSync](https://github.com/SparkPost/node-sparkpost/blob/master/lib/SendGridCompatibility/index.js) to read the file. Maybe even call `toString()` on it.